Strange behaviour (out of memory) of groupby function in python
I have a long code that at some point has a very small dataframe with 813 rows and 16 columns.
To this dataframe i apply the groupby function
fm = fm.groupby(['Tower_ID'                 ,'Cell_ID'                 ,'Alarm ID'                 ,'Severity'                 ,'Alarm Type'                 ,'Alarm Text'                 ,'Supplementary Info'                 ,'PERIOD_START_TIME'                 #,'File_Name'                ]
               ).agg({'Full_Start_Date': 'min'
                      ,'Full_End_Date': 'max'
                      ,'Alarm hold time (sec)': 'sum'
                      ,'End_Date': 'max'
                      ,'Cross_Over': 'max'
                      ,'Cross_Over_diff': 'max'
                     }
                    )

This results in an error of out of memory
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.1 GiB for an array with shape (1485993600,) and data type int64
Things that i have tried.
1 - Instead of fm = fm  i used different variable like bananas = fm.groupby ..... same result
2 - Tried changing the formats of the columns to the exact type i need, category, int, etc.... same result
What worked
Before the groupby i save the fm dataframe into a file and then read the file back into fm
fm.to_excel('C:\\home\\fm_data.xlsx')
fm = pd.read_excel('C:\\home\\fm_data.xlsx')

And this works!!!
Can anyone have an ideia of why?
This is a very very poor solution and i would want to understand what can be the problem.
I appreciate the help.

If you're using categorical dtypes, try adding observed=True to your groupby call.

If you want to .agg for each unique id, the .groupby you are using has a major issue. It will run over all possible combinations of eight (8) unique ids which is 256 unique combinations. If you want .agg for each independent ids, here is the code you can utilise:
# Columns to group by
group_columns = [
   'Tower_ID', 'Cell_ID', 'Alarm ID', 'Severity', 'Alarm Type', 
   'Alarm Text', 'Supplementary Info', 'PERIOD_START_TIME'
]

# Aggregation columns to dictionary
agg_dict = {
    'Full_Start_Date': 'min',
    'Full_End_Date': 'max',
    'Alarm hold time (sec)': 'sum',
    'End_Date': 'max',
    'Cross_Over': 'max',
    'Cross_Over_diff': 'max'
}

# performs groupby and aggregation for each ID column separately
grouped_dfs = {}
for col in group_columns:
   grouped_dfs[col] = fm.groupby(col).agg(agg_dict).reset_index()

If you really want to run all possible combinations of the 8 unique ids it is very expensive process to run and normal to get out of memory error.
Lets breakdown the math here:

If each of groupby columns only has 1 unique element there will be 2^{8} = 256 unique combinations.
Considering 813 rows, I guess there will average minimum of 20 unique elements in each column. Which is: 2^{20*8} = 1,4615e48. 1 with 48 zeroes is really big number to calculate.

